# NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData conversion issue

Tags: ekevent

I am using the following code to convert `NSArray` `EKEvent` to `NSData` and the converted `NSData` is `unarchiveObjectWithData` to `NSArray`. While converting, the object is changed and it holds the `null` value.

Why does it show  **`NULL`**. (Refer to the output). Anyone know the solution let me know. Thanks in Advance.

The code I written,

```
NSArray *events = [[self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate]retain];

NSData *arrayData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:events];

NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:arrayData];
```

The Output is

> events : (
>       "EKEvent <0x4ad840> {EKEvent <0x4ad840> {title = **Checking with Calendar**; calendar = EKCalendar <0x4bf2f0> {title = Calendar; type = Local; account = (null); allowsModify = YES; color = 0.443137 0.101961 0.462745 1.000000}; alarms = (\n    \"EKAlarm <0x4be630> {triggerInterval = -300.000000}\"\n); URL = (null); lastModified = 2012-05-14 12:15:32 +0000}; location = (null); startDate = 2012-05-11 01:30:00 +0000; endDate = 2012-05-19 17:30:00 +0000; allDay = 0; floating = 0; recurrence = (null); attendees = (null)}"
>   )
>   Array : (
>       "EKEvent <0x4c1e60> {EKEvent <0x4c1e60> {title = (**null**); calendar = (null); alarms = (null); URL = (null); lastModified = (null)}; location = (null); startDate = (null); endDate = (null); allDay = 0; floating = 1; recurrence = (null); attendees = (null)}"
>   )

Answer (score 1):

Finally Solved by creating custom EKEvent class and getting every value like title, startdate, enddate to NSCoding. Then it works fine.

Comment: You think you could provide your solution? I am having issues with this... At least the coding part :P

Answer (score 0):

While `NSArray` confirms to the `NSCoding` protocol, `EKEvent` does not. It's a bit surprising that you don't get an exception running the code, the class must confirm to `NSCoding` for archiving to work.

Comment: Thanks Per Johansson, I will try wiht NSCoding and let you know.

Comment: I used custom class and confirmed with NSCoding but it doesn't work.

it always give the result as 


**EKEvent <0x46ba50> {EKEvent <0x46ba50> {title = (null); calendar = (null); alarms = (null); URL = (null); lastModified = (null)}; location = (null); startDate = (null); endDate = (null); allDay = 0; floating = 1; recurrence = (null); attendees = (null)}**